# My quota is full

Tags: google-maps-api-3

My quota is full trying to get Google Maps API keys. I read somewhere that it's possible for you to increase the quota. Is this possible?

I'm building a lot of sites and always need to get that API key.

Answer (score 0):

If you have "Google Maps APIs Premium Plan", you might.
Read this document.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage

Answer (score 0):

You want to delete some unnecessary API keys and try to create a new key.